# SPFX Login Popup Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, login

We tried internally to follow the steps here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadtokenprovider#handling-the-popupevent

but it didn't work. This line we could not figure out how to write:

```
import {
  PlaceholderContent,
  BaseApplicationCustomizer,
  PlaceholderName
} from '@microsoft/sp-application-base';
import { AadHttpClient, AadHttpClientFactory, AadTokenProvider, AadTokenProviderFactory, BeforeRedirectEventArgs, IHttpClientOptions, IPopupEventArgs, TokenAcquisitionEventArgs } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import { uniqueId } from 'lodash';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { IMegaMenuProps } from './IMegaMenu/IMegaMenu';
import { developmentApiPath } from './IMegaMenu/Util';
import { MegaMenuAPIService } from './MegaMenuAPIService/IMegaMenuAPIService';
import { IMegaMenuWrapperProps, MegaMenuWrapper } from './MegaMenuWrapper/MegaMenuWrapper';
import { AppSettings } from "../../IAppSettings";
import { IMatrixMenuProps } from './MegaMenuWrapper/MatrixMenuView';
import { SPFx, spfi } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import { ISPEventObserver } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';

export interface ILivetilesMegaMenuApplicationCustomizerProperties {
  Top: string; 
}

export default class LivetilesMegaMenuApplicationCustomizer
  extends BaseApplicationCustomizer<ILivetilesMegaMenuApplicationCustomizerProperties> {
  private _topPlaceholder: PlaceholderContent | undefined;
  private megaMenu:IMegaMenuProps;  
  private token:any
  private matrixMenu:IMatrixMenuProps;  
  public async onInit(): Promise<void> {

    const factory: AadHttpClientFactory = this.context.aadHttpClientFactory;
    const client = await factory.getClient(AppSettings.clientId);
    const tokenProviderFactory: AadTokenProviderFactory = this.context.aadTokenProviderFactory;
    const tokenProvider = await tokenProviderFactory.getTokenProvider();
    
    
    const configurableTokenProvider: AadTokenProvider = tokenProvider as AadTokenProvider;

    configurableTokenProvider.popupEvent.add(this, (args: IPopupEventArgs) => {
      args.cancel();     // REQUIRED: to cancel the default popup that is called to open
      args.showPopup();  // initiate the popup flow
    });

    await configurableTokenProvider.getToken(AppSettings.clientId)
    .then((t) => {
      this.token = t;
    })
    .catch((tokenError) => {
      console.debug("getToken expetion", tokenError);
    });

    await this.getMegaMenu(client, this.token);
    this.context.application.navigatedEvent.add(this, async () => {await this._renderPlaceHolders()})
    //this.context.placeholderProvider.changedEvent.add(this, async () => {await this._renderPlaceHolders()});
    const sp = spfi().using(SPFx(this.context));
    const webData = await sp.web(); 
    return Promise.resolve();
    
  }

  private async getMegaMenu(client:AadHttpClient, token:string): Promise<IMegaMenuProps>
  {   
    return new Promise<IMegaMenuProps>((resolve) => {
      MegaMenuAPIService.getMenu(client,token,this.context.pageContext.aadInfo.tenantId, this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl).then(response =>{
        response.json().then((data)=>{
          this.megaMenu = data.megaMenu;
          this.matrixMenu = data.matrixNavigation;
          resolve(this.megaMenu);
        })
      }).catch((menuError) => {console.debug("getMenu expetion", menuError);});
    });
  }

  private async _renderPlaceHolders(): Promise<void>
  {
    if (!this._topPlaceholder) {
      this._topPlaceholder = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(
        PlaceholderName.Top
      );
    }
    if (this._topPlaceholder.domElement)
    {
      this.renderMegaMenu(this._topPlaceholder.domElement);
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  private renderMegaMenu(parentElement: Element){
    this.megaMenu.generalOptions.primaryLanguage.languageName = this.megaMenu.generalOptions.primaryLanguage.languageCode;
    this.megaMenu.generalOptions.primaryLanguage.languageCode = this.context.pageContext.cultureInfo.currentUICultureName.toLowerCase();
    
    const props: IMegaMenuWrapperProps = {
      megaMenu: this.megaMenu,
      matrixMenu: this.matrixMenu,
      context: this.context
    }
    console.log("Current language used in the mega menu: ", props.megaMenu.generalOptions.primaryLanguage.languageName)
    const element = React.createElement<IMegaMenuWrapperProps>(MegaMenuWrapper,props);
    element.key = uniqueId();
    ReactDOM.render(element,parentElement);
    
  }
}
```

So we created the token provider differently and never got any popup requests.

Has anyone been successful in implementing this?

Comment: Do you get any errors when you add above line of code? If yes, what is error message?/

Comment: @GaneshSanap: thanks for the answer, I edited the question with the code we produced.

Comment: @user3181876 hey, any luck with this? We also tried and it didn't work. Still getting page refreshes instead of popup.

Comment: hey @AlexK, not yet - given how stuck and how the documentation didnt help, we needed to switch focus internally. Hopefully MS will adjust their documentation eventually

Comment: @user3181876 looks like Microsoft acknowledged it's a bug and going to fix it https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/8881

Comment: @AlexK: that is a topic I opened on their github, glad to see it is getting traction